# After Resizing the two or three divs, that divs overlap?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to do the draggable and resizable jquery ui api. But when i am resizing the top div, the next divs come up to the top. 
pls see the example code here

http://jsfiddle.net/wExtX/190/
waiting the reply

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because when we try to re-size the top div then jQuery change the position of div "position:relative" to "position:absolute"